# Select sum and dynamic where statement query in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have this below statement in my controller and I want to know how to rewrite it in Rails 4

```
Entry.find(:all, :conditions => [@conditions.keys.join(" AND "), *@conditions.values],:group => "user_id",                                 :select => "SUM(time_spent) AS total_spent")
```

The condition has the user_id information in it like `"user_id=?"`.

The statement is trying to find the entry for a particular user id and sum the time spent for the user id and group by user id.

Comment: Could you give more information about condition?

Comment: The condition has the user_id information in it like "user_id=?". the statement is trying to find the entry for a particular user id and sum the time spent for the user id and group by user id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can use it

```
realations = Entry.where(user_id: [1, 2, 3]).select("SUM(time_spent) as total_spent").group(:user_id)
```

After that you have relation with which you can work

```
realations.each do |i|
  puts i.total_spent
end
```